# What to enclose in square brackets and not?

Tags: punctuation, quotations, square-brackets

I use square brackets when I paraphrase, i.e. when I change or add some words to a text I quote. I have noticed an inconsistency in what I enclose in the square brackets and not. Here are two examples.

> - 1a Original:
>
> ... another strategy is to moderate the neutrons so they interact more
> readily and we get more neutron signal. For some detectors, the
> interaction products deposit much more energy than do gamma rays. For
> example, helium-3, or with boron, the charged particles ...
>
> - 1b Amended:
>
> ... another strategy is to moderate the neutrons so they interact more
> readily and [increase the neutron signal in the neutron-gamma signal
> ratio. Thirdly, for] some detectors, the interaction products deposit
> much more energy than do gamma rays. For example, [in helium-3 or in
> boron-10], the charged particles ...

Should the first ] follow after f in for? This maybe makes it less readable, but on the other hand is more consistent with the use of square brackets when changing capitalization, see [here](https://style.mla.org/changing-initial-capital-letter/). Also, in the last pair of square brackets, helium-3 and or are words that are not changed or added. Hence only the two occurrences of in and -10 may be enclosed by square brackets. This maybe also makes it less readable. However, suppose one would, how would then the omission of the comma after helium-3 be dealt with?

> - 2a Original:
>
> Finally, the same effect can be used to discriminate against gammas
> because the collection speed for the induced charge for neutron
> products and for gamma rays may be very different. We can use...
>
> - 1b Amended:
>
> Finally…[since] the collection speed [of] the induced [charges] for
> neutron products and for gamma rays may be very [different, one] can
> use...

Should the last [ follow after t in different? Also, should only s in charges be enclosed by square brackets? If it were the other way around, so the original would say charges and the quote would say charge, how would that be dealt with?

Comment: There are many different practices for editorial insertions in quoted text. A style guide (Chicago, APA, etc.) is probably the best place to look first. If you've already done so, then please explain why that didn't help.

Comment: Yes. Where a virtual rewrite is indicated, it's possibly better to suggest the improved version to the author.

Comment: You should avoid too many square brackets. It makes it harder to read and suggests you're twisting the text. If necessary you can format as a direct quotation introduced by "X says" or "X describes their process as", or just paraphrase, rather than try and fit a quote into your description with lots of changes.